# running a function on a group of templated objects

Tags: c++, templates

Im trying to make a class template that will have a vector of objects, and that will be able to run a function of the objects class on them, so i dont have to loop throw the objects and run the class i could just right something like

```cpp
allObjects.runFunc(objectsType::someFunc);
```

in the class I want 3 commands:

- `add` - that adds an item to the Group
- `remove` - reomves an Item
- `runFunc(someFunc)` - thats the most important one, and i want it to run the `someFunc` on all the objects in the Group

and the class will have one varible:
`std::vector<Object> objects` - that will store all of the objects

so Ive looked alot on the internet and havent found what i needed yet
I tried using std::bind and got some really wierd glitches.

the class (in a .h file):

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <vector>


template<class Object>
class Group {
public:
    void add(Object &object);
    void runFunc(void(Object::* func)(void));

private:
    std::vector<Object> objects;
};

template<class Object>
inline void Group<Object>::add(Object &object)
{
    objects.push_back(object);
}

template<class Object>
inline void Group<Object>::runFunc(void (Object::* func)(void))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
    {
        (objects[i].func)();
    }
}
```

the error i get is func is not a member of gameObject
where gameobject is the type that Im testing the group on, and yes, it does have an update function.

Comment: Have a look at [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your invocation looks wrong (think: `func` is pointer to function):

Replace this line:

```
(objects[i].func)();
```

*with*

```
(objects[i].*func)();
```

That being said, I would highly recommend using `std::function` and perhaps also `std::bind` instead of '*raw function pointers*' (when it looks like you are not constrained by a 3rd party library).

Comment: @eitan03 Please accept the answer if it helped you to solve your problem.